# How to delete shared contacts?

Tags: iphone

Someone shared their contacts with me and I don't know how to delete them. I've opened the contacts app but I don't see them. I only see them when I'm writing a new text message and they show up in the auto complete field.

Groups says

- All iCloud
- Group name

Comment: Open Contacts and click groups in the top left corner and see if that gives any clues.

Comment: It has two groups. Both selected.